# Python dataframe vector norm efficient

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'd like to calculate for each row of a dataframe the norm (i.e. the length of the vector in euclidean distance). I know functions like `mean()` and `sum()` exist but no `norm()`. So I tried implementing it myself by doing

```
df.apply(lambda values: math.sqrt(sum([v**2 for v in values])), axis=1)
```

but this is realy slow compared to e.g. the sum function. Is there a simple (and fast) pandas implementation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `numpy` here:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])

In [3]: np.linalg.norm(df, axis=1)
Out[3]: array([3.74165739, 8.77496439])
```